# Typeahead with ag-Grid

Tags: angularjs, ag-grid, bootstrap-typeahead

I am trying to implement typeahead in ag-Grid using Angular 1. The typeahead implementation shown in ag-Grid documentation site is using ng2-typeahead which is an Angular 2 typeahead.

Since the application I am working on is Angular 1.5 based, I tried implementing Angular typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead) using cell-editor. Somehow, it doesn't seem to work in the grid. The column in which I am trying to bring in typeahead is 'Release'. The cell-editor I have created is 'ReleaseEditor'. I am using a live JSON service for getting the data. It would be great if somone could help me with this.

**Cell Editor created**

```
function ReleaseEditor() {
}

ReleaseEditor.prototype.init = function (params) {
    this.eInput = document.createElement('input');
    this.eInput.setAttribute("typeahead", "suggestion for suggestion in cities($viewValue)");
    this.eInput.setAttribute("typeahead-wait-ms", "300");
    this.eInput.setAttribute("ng-model", "result");
    this.eInput.value = params.value;

};

ReleaseEditor.prototype.getGui = function () {
    return this.eInput;
};

ReleaseEditor.prototype.afterGuiAttached = function () {
    this.eInput.focus();

};

ReleaseEditor.prototype.getValue = function () {
    return this.eInput.value;
};
```

[This is the link to the plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/sbM5kewn8mD0w8qkv5ZO).

Answer (score 0):

On setting `angularCompileRows:true` on the `gridOptions` object, it is working now. I have updated the working demo under the plnkr,
http://plnkr.co/edit/sbM5kewn8mD0w8qkv5ZO?p=preview